# How to pass ArrayList from Java to User Defined Function and iterate

Tags: db2, user-defined-functions

I would need to pass this `_objList` from java to the User Defined Function. In java, it is something like below.

```
List _objList = new ArrayList(); 
Object[] p1 = new Object[] { _groupid, _date, _amount }; 
Object[] p2 = new Object[] { _groupid2, _date2, _amount2 }; 
_objList.add(p1); 
_objList.add(p2);
```

I would like to know how should I pass this `_objList` to User Defined Function and how to iterate through this `_objList` in the User Defined Function?

I am using DB2 9.5.

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far, and what hasn't worked?  Searching on this site should reveal to you that, in general, SQL doesn't support array types; the closest you can get tends to be bulk inserts to tables... (hint)

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I am looking at this link now http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0710arocena/

Comment: Hunh, that's a new one on me.  Regardless.... what part of following those directions are you having trouble with?  What _specific problem_ are you encountering?  From the look of things, you may have to define a new type to use them in a stored procedure.  Also, if you can avoid it, you usually don't want to iterate through an array - SQL is usually better at set-based (all-at-once, sort of) operations.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Thanks for advice. In the example, it shows as creating a type array of varchar. Is it possible to create a type of array of array?

Comment: ...This is not a discussion forum.  This is a site for you to get help for _specific problems you are encountering_.  In general, "does this work" questions are to be avoided - you should try it yourself, then (if it doesn't work) report what you tried and the steps you attempted to resolve it, asking assistance for the specific error/problem.  Failure to do so can stunt your own growth/learning, and turns this site into Cthuluism.  Try creating an array of arrays, in several different ways (and search more online) - I don't actually have a DB2 instance to test against...